# Is it possible to change the transaction controller response time in the JSR223 post processor?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Guys I need to manually set the end time for the transaction controller in the jsr223 post processor
I tried the following:

- prev.getParent().setEndTime()
- SampleResult.getParent().setEndTime()

And it didn't help, getParent always returns null. Could you please help me? Maybe there are other ways to do it?
I use jmeter 5.4.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnv5u.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to set the time for the Transaction Controller you need to meet the following criteria:

1. Transaction Controller should have `Generate parent sample` box ticked

   [image]

   otherwise you will override response time only for the last child sub-sample. See [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) article for more details.
2. I believe it's better to do it from [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which should be placed after the Transaction Controller and the code in its turn should be something like:

   ```
   ctx.getPreviousResult().getParent().elapsedTime=1234
   ```

   [image]